# Azure Web App Ruby runtime version different from the one specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, azure

I created a Azure Web App to run a Ruby on Rails app.
I specified Ruby runtime version 2.6

[image]

The app works locally with "rails server".
Although, when deploying the app with local git I can see the build agent is using ruby 2.3.8 :

```
git push azure-stage master
Enumerating objects: 12, done.
Counting objects: 100% (12/12), done.
...
remote: Bundle install with no 'without' options
remote: Defaulting gem installation directory to /tmp/bundle
remote: Defaulting site config directory to /home/site/config
remote: Using ruby version 2.3.8
remote: /home/site/wwwroot
remote: Found gemfile
remote: ~/site/wwwroot ~/site/repository
remote: Setting ruby version
remote: Running bundle clean
...
remote: ahoy_matey-3.1.0 requires ruby version >= 2.4, which is incompatible with the
remote: current version, ruby 2.3.3p222
remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.
remote: bundler failed
```

Anyone have any idea why this is happening and how to solve it?

When running the quickstart example I can see the build agent also uses ruby 2.3.8
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-ruby

Comment: What is the Ruby version specified in your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock?

Comment: I haven't specified any Ruby version in either of those files.

Comment: Try to specify version of Ruby in Gemfile
ruby "2.6.0"
Then run command bundle update --ruby
Commit your Gemfile.lock
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions#ruby-version-specifiers